# What is lsof -i | grep -E "(LISTEN|ESTABLISHED)" composed of?

Tags: macos, unix

I got advice to check if an iTunes app sends data to the cloud using this command line

```
lsof -i | grep -E "(LISTEN|ESTABLISHED)"
```

Can someone please explain how this works? How does the pipeline work here?

Comment: What is an iTunes app?

Answer (score 6):

First `lsof` is executed:

```
lsof - list open files
```

with the option -i:

> -i [i]   selects  the  listing  of  files any of whose Internet address
>                   matches the address specified in i.  If no address  is  speci-
>                   fied, this option selects the listing of all Internet and x.25
>                   (HP-UX) network files.

So you get a list similar to this:

```
Safari      252 pfitz   33u  IPv4 0x1052718d4b4f54ef      0t0  TCP localhost:49289->localhost:6263 (ESTABLISHED)
Safari      252 pfitz   36u  IPv4 0x1052718d4b4f54ef      0t0  TCP localhost:49289->localhost:6263 (ESTABLISHED)
iTunes      254 pfitz   28u  IPv4 0x1052718d460f9d07      0t0  TCP *:49196 (LISTEN)
iTunes      254 pfitz   30u  IPv4 0x1052718d460fb4ef      0t0  TCP *:daap (LISTEN)
iTunes      254 pfitz   31u  IPv6 0x1052718d37b6b627      0t0  TCP *:daap (LISTEN)
```

with a lot more entries. To filter the entries one uses `grep`:

> The grep utility searches any given input files, selecting lines that
>   match one or more patterns.  By default, a pattern matches an input
>   line if
>        the regular expression (RE) in the pattern matches the input line without its trailing newline.  An empty expression matches every line.
>   Each
>        input line that matches at least one of the patterns is written to the standard output.
>
> grep is used for simple patterns and basic regular expressions (BREs); egrep can handle extended regular expressions (EREs).  See
>   re_format(7) for
>        more information on regular expressions.  fgrep is quicker than both grep and egrep, but can only handle fixed patterns (i.e. it does
>   not interpret
>        regular expressions).  Patterns may consist of one or more lines, allowing any of the pattern lines to match a portion of the input.

and the option -E does the following:

> -E, --extended-regexp
>
> Interpret pattern as an extended regular expression (i.e. force grep to behave as 
>   egrep).

The regex in this case is `"(LISTEN|ESTABLISHED)"` which means just print the lines with listen or established.

### Conclusion

1. lsof builds a list with all Internet connections.
2. To be useful it needs to be filtered with grep
3. So it gets filtered with the regular expression which is looking for either *LISTEN* or *ESTABLISHED*